# How can i use "uri" to send an image to another class? (android)

Tags: android, image, uri

i took an image from gallery and i want to use it on another class. Is it possible with using "uri"?

```
Uri  selectedImage = data.getData();
String path = selectedImage.getPath();

Intent sintent = new Intent(FromFile.this, OurView.class);
startActivity(sintent);
```

Comment: You want to send the `Path` or `Uri`

Comment: it is best to use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setDataAndType(android.net.Uri, java.lang.String) or something similar

Answer (score 1):

Add this after creating the intent.

```
sintent.putExtra("image", path);
```

And in OurView call

```
String path = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `Uri` of the image you want to send in the intent of your sender's `Activity`. Something like this:

```
Intent sintent = new Intent(FromFile.this, OurView.class);
intent.putExtra("selectedImage", selectedImage.toString());
startActivity(sintent);
```

Then to retrieve it, use this code in the `Activity` that is beeing called:

```
//Where OurView is assumed to be the class name of your Activity that is being called
Uri selectedImage = Uri.parse(OurView.this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("selectedImage"));
```

Answer (score 0):

1) If you want to pass the Path to next Activity. Try this -

```
Intent sintent = new Intent(FromFile.this, OurView.class);
sintent.putExtra("pathvalue", path);
startActivity(sintent);
```

in nextActivity(OurView.java) -

```
String path = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
```

2) If you want to pass the Uri to next Activity. Try this -

```
Uri  selectedImage = data.getData();
String path = selectedImage.getPath();

Intent intent = new Intent(FromFile.this, OurView.class);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(selectedImage));
startActivity(intent);
```

in nextActivity(OurView.java) -

```
Uri selectedImage = getIntent().getData();
```